# How to unget string to file Ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing

What is the best way to organize work with lines of file, when I need to unget them to the file.
I need to parse large file (~3,5 m lines) using Ruby. But I need to parse only about 50000 lines from the place given when the program is started. So I need to organize fast search through this file. I was told to use binary search. But I don't know the way how to return lines to the file when they are not matching. E.g. I have get lines upto the middle of the file and I found, that my lines are in the first half; and I need to unget strings. How do I do this?

Comment: Can't you convert the text file to something friendlier like a database of some sort?

Comment: It seems I need to process the given file

Comment: Process it into an SQLite (or even DBM) database first. Otherwise you'll end up going backward and forward byte by byte using [`seek`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/IO.html#method-i-seek) to figure out where the record separators (i.e. newlines) are. Either that or manually build an index of which stores the offset of the beginning of each line. Dealing with variable record length data files without an index is silly and a big waste of time and effort.